# Why cant we delay initialise a class member with a non default constructor?

Tags: c++11, constructor, default-constructor

I have a class like below:

```
#pragma once
#include <atomic>

class MyClassAnother {
public:
    MyClassAnother(int val) : m_val(val) {
    }

private:
    int m_val;
};
```

There is another class which holds an object to `MyClassAnother`

```
#pragma once
#include "MyClassAnother.hpp"

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() {

    }

    void Func() {
        anotherClassObject = MyClassAnother(2);
    }

private:
    MyClassAnother anotherClassObject;
};
```

And here is the `main.cpp`

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   MyClass object;
}
```

Of course the program does not compile. And its because of the following error

> error: constructor for 'MyClass' must explicitly initialize the member
>   'anotherClassObject' which does not have a default
>         constructor

**Question:**
But why? Why can't I delay initialise the class member? Is the workaround to have a default constructor and delay initialise it with the real constructor later? Is it an anti pattern to do it this way then?

I know that this can be resolved by making `MyClassAnother anotherClassObject` a pointer. But I want to have `MyClassAnother anotherClassObject` as a member object or a reference member in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor must guarantee that all members are properly constructed and initialized, and this one doesn't do that. What happens if you forget to call `Func()` and then access `objcect.anotherClassObject`?

Delayed initialization in general could be considered an anti-pattern, and goes against the [RAII idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), which states that object construction should succeed if and only if initialization of underlying resources (`MyClassAnother` in this case) succeeded. It's a good pattern to follow, because it prevents having unusable objects around because they failed to initialize properly, or because somebody forgot to perform their delayed initialization steps.

If `MyClass` objects are actually usable without a `MyClassAnother` instance, you can wrap the latter in an `std::unique_pointer` (C++11) or an `std::optional` (C++17).

If `MyClass` objects are not usable without a `MyClassAnother` instance, you need to pass that instance to the constructor, or create it in the constructor's initializer list.